# Why does a delete statement affect an additional row?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-execution-plan

**UPDATE**:

*I have found that including the actual execution plan was the culprit of adding that additional row affected warning.*

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm deleting a few hundreds of thousands of unnecessary records, on batches of 100 records.

My question is that I see a warning of (1 row affected) after every 100 rows delete instruction and I'm wondering what could it be.

My table doesn't have any trigger, and it doesn't have relationships with cascades. So, do you know of anything else that could be affecting an additional row ?.

```
DECLARE @LOOP bit = 1

WHILE @LOOP = 1
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION 

  DELETE TOP (100) FICHERO_ASIGNACION
  FROM FICHERO_ASIGNACION 
       INNER JOIN FICHERO ON FICHERO.FIC_KEY = FICHERO_ASIGNACION.FIC_KEY
  WHERE FAT_KEY = 4 and 
        CLI_COD is null and
        FIC_BUC = 'prd.factura-venta'

  PRINT '100 unneeded assignments deleted'
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SET @LOOP = 0
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

This is the result :

```
(100 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
100 unneeded assignments deleted
(100 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
100 unneeded assignments deleted
(100 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
100 unneeded assignments deleted
...
...
```

Also, on the execution plan I don't see any reference to additional tables or other searches.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I know you've said there's no trigger but please double and triple check that. Also, your loop should never loop - `print` will reset `@@ROWCOUNT` to 0, no matter how many rows were affected by the `DELETE`.

Comment: Damien, I think this is the answer....

Comment: Also check is there any relationship in other table with a cascade delete.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed - cascading deletes don't report row counts from the cascaded tables, unless I seriously misremember things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that the additional row warning was raised by showing the Execution Plan.

I have removed the "Include Actual Execution Plan" and now it doesn't show any additional row affected.

Thank you all.

Comment: Doh! I guess I have seen that in the past but never given it much thought since I'd usually already be chasing some other issue at the point at which I'm generating plans.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. check [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/930539). 
Is there a trigger on the table?.

Comment: Thans @Praveen, but I have rechecked several times, and I don't have triggers or cascaded updates.

Comment: So its the execution plan!
Good one :)